# Laravel query variable as string

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

What i am doing here might be stupid but i am newbie to laravel, 
I am applying search filters for database using a query.
Query is being built using javascript and being passed to laravel function.
E.g.

```
window.open("/filterResults?types="+types);
//types contains a string like "international#global#europe#  etc
```

Now in Controller i am getting that string `types` and exploding it to make a query like this

```
    $tquery = "Where('type',".$typesArray[0].")";
    for($offset=1; $offset < count($typesArray); $offset++) {
        $tquery .= "->orWhere('type', ".$typesArray[$offset].")";
    }
```

and executing query like this

```
$firms = Firm::$tquery->get();
```

it gives me error

```
Access to undeclared static property: App\Firm::$tquery
```

How can i do what i want to.

PS. types are checkboxes some of them can be checked or all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to use [`whereIn()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses) method:

```
$firms = Firm::whereIn('type', $typesArray)->get();
```

But if you need to use your way, you can do something like this:

```
$firm = new App\Firm;

foreach ($typesArray as $type) {
    $firm = $firm->orWhere('type', $type);
}

$firms = $firm->get();
```

Comment: Awesome `whereIn` Rocks, :) Thanks Man.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider query builder ?

```
$firmsQuery = (new Firm)->newQuery();

if($request->has('types')) {
    $typesArray =  $request->input('types');

    foreach ($typesArray as $type) {
        $firmsQuery->where(function($query) use ($type) {
            $query->orWhere('type', $type);
        });
    }

}

$firms = $firmsQuery->get();
```

Comment: Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::newQuery() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Comment: Whoops! Check updated answer please. There was an unintentional mistake. It should be `$firmsQuery = (new Firm)->newQuery();`

Comment: Thankyou for your attention and time, but now the error is `Undefined variable: type`

Comment: Fixed. It supposed to be `$typesArray` in `foreach`. `foreach ($typesArray as $type)`

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are using bad style but you can take a look to [DB Raw Expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#raw-expressions)